# How do I remotely open a bank account in Thailand?

Tags: banking, online-banking, online-payment, paypal, thailand

A friend of mine told me that Thai bank account has no limitations in paypal for transfers, etc. I would like to try it out and open bank account in Thailand, register paypal account for it and use it for money transfers. But the thing is that I live in other country and would like to open the account remotely.

Is this has any thing what I should take into consideration?

P.S. This was inspired by Paypal Freeze horrors %)

Comment: the only thing to take into consideration is: don't be American.

Answer (score 2):

With the recent drive in AML [Anti Money Laundering], quite a few countries being signatories; the central banks in almost all countries[that matter] have put in stronger KYC guidelines. This means you will not be able to remotely open a Bank Account in Thailand. More info at below links

http://www.bangkokbank.com/BANGKOKBANK/PERSONALBANKING/SPECIALSERVICES/FOREIGNCUSTOMERS/Pages/Openinganaccountnew.aspx

http://www.samuifinder.com/en/koh-samui-info/money-in-thailand/bank-account-thailand/